# Changing the order of elements according to screen size

Tags: html, css-float, css-position

I have two floating `<div>`'s `.a` and `.b`.

Both `<div>`'s   are floated to left, So that they both are aligned horizontally with `50%` width for each.

But on small screen I want both `<div>`'s to be aligned vertically with full width but second `<div>` `.b` must  appear first and first `<div>` `.a` must appear under `<div>` `.b`.

Also I can't set height on both `<div>`'s since their content is dynamic.

Following is sample code:

```css
.a{width:50%; float:left;background-color:#CCCCCC}
.b{width:50%; float:left; background-color:#FFC;}

@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {
.a{width:100%; float:left; background-color:#CCCCCC}
.b{width:100%; float:left; background-color:#FFC;}
}
```

```html
<div class="a">This is first div</div>
<div class="b">this is Second div</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Alright, let's get into it.* You want them to be left aligned in large resolutions, but inverted in mobile resolutions.

**Mobile version:** Let's take a mobile-first approach. This means we will support the mobile styles as the default, and include large-screen styles in the media query. It seems much simpler and more reasonable, since your divs can be static in that case. Then, it makes a lot more sense to have the second div come first.:

```
<div class="section">Second div</div>
<div class="section">First div</div>
```

Then, there's not much to style, just regular simple css for the mobile version. Mainly this:

```
.section {
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

Check an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/arthurcamara/3yv2urkm/

**Large screen version:** I also took the freedom to make the code more semantic. So I added separate classes `lg-right` and `lg-left` to the divs:

```
<div class="section lg-right">Text, second div</div>
<div class="section lg-left">Text, first div </div>
```

Now it comes to adding your media query.

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 481px) {
    .section {
        width: 50%;
    }
    .lg-right {
        float: right;
    }
    .lg-left {
        float: left;
    }
}
```

See final working version here: http://jsfiddle.net/arthurcamara/3yv2urkm/2/

Also, you might want to consider using a framework such as [Foundation](http://foundation.zurb.com/). They already provide this functionality in a much broader and flexible way then the one I presented.

Answer (score 2):

**[fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/met1zb6c/2/)**

Invert the HTML order:

```
<div class="b">this is Second div</div>
<div class="a">This is first div</div>
```

use `float:right` initially:

```
.a{width:50%; float:right; background:#ccc}
.b{width:50%; float:right; background:#ffc;}

@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {
  .a{width:100%; float:left;}
  .b{width:100%; float:left;}
}
```

Comment: Thank for reply but Change in html structure  not possible its a responsive website.

Comment: @Joginder sorry to say but HTML-elements-order and responsiveness have nothing to do one with the other. :|

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/order) property of CSS3 [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes) module as follows:

HTML:

```
<div class="flex-parent">
  <div class="flex-child a">This is first div</div>
  <div class="flex-child b">this is Second div</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.flex-parent {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width:100%;
}
.flex-child {
  flex:1;
}
.a {
  background-color: #CCCCCC
}
.b {
  background-color: #FFC;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 480px) {
  .flex-child {
    flex-basis:100%;
  }
  .a {
    order:2;
  }
  .b {
    order:1;
  }
}
```

### [JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kbLo3jee/2)

flexbox browser support@ [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)